# Prevent checkbox from being selected in Javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a JavaScript function that checks if a checkbox is selected.

If yes, It count how many check boxes are selected and checks if the max number of selected (4) is reached.

The thing is:

How can I make that the function show an alert and disable all the unchecked check boxes when I try to check a fifth?

Even the one that was tried to be checked as the 5 one.

```
 function ChkValidate() {

          var chkDytLek = document.getElementById("ChkDytLek");
          var chkDytUSD = document.getElementById("ChkDytUSD");
          var chkDytEU = document.getElementById("ChkDytEU");
          var chkDytCAD = document.getElementById("ChkDytCAD");
          var chkDytCHF = document.getElementById("ChkDytCHF");
          var chkDytAUD = document.getElementById("ChkDytAUD");
          var chkDytGBP = document.getElementById("ChkDytGBP");

          var MaxCount = 0
          var unCheckedCount = 0

          if (chkDytLek.checked == true) {
              MaxCount = MaxCount + 1

              if (MaxCount == 4) {

                  disableIfNotChecked();
              }
          } else {
              unCheckedCount = unCheckedCount + 1 
          }

          if (ChkDytUSD.checked == true) {
              MaxCount = MaxCount + 1

              if (MaxCount == 4) {
                  disableIfNotChecked();
              }
          } else {
              unCheckedCount = unCheckedCount + 1
          }  
          if (ChkDytEU.checked == true) {
              MaxCount = MaxCount + 1
              if (MaxCount == 4) {
                  disableIfNotChecked();
              }
          } else {
              unCheckedCount = unCheckedCount + 1
          }

          if (ChkDytCAD.checked == true) {
              MaxCount = MaxCount + 1

              if (MaxCount == 4) {
                  disableIfNotChecked();
              }
          } else {
              unCheckedCount = unCheckedCount + 1
          }

          if (ChkDytCHF.checked == true) {
              MaxCount = MaxCount + 1

              if (MaxCount == 4) {
                  disableIfNotChecked();
              }
          } else {
              unCheckedCount = unCheckedCount + 1
          }
          if (ChkDytGBP.checked == true) {
              MaxCount = MaxCount + 1

              if (MaxCount == 4) {
                  disableIfNotChecked();
              }
          } else {
              unCheckedCount = unCheckedCount + 1
          }

          if (ChkDytAUD.checked == true) {
              MaxCount = MaxCount + 1

              if (MaxCount == 4) {
                  disableIfNotChecked();


              }
          } else {
              unCheckedCount = unCheckedCount + 1
          }

           if (unCheckedCount >= 4) {                  
              enableIfNotChecked();
           }


      }
```

The current code displays an alert and disables the checkboxes when the count is 4.

When I want this to happen at the 5 one, but if I change this:

```
 if (MaxCount == 4) {
                  disableIfNotChecked();
```

to:

```
 if (MaxCount == 5) {
                  disableIfNotChecked();
```

The code will disable the check boxes but will also check the one that was selected as the 5.

Any idea how can I give a solution to this situation?

Comment: i'm guessing you're calling ChkValidate() on the check event of a checkbox, could you post that code? that's where you need to uncheck the box that you currently checked, probably by returning a false or something from ChkValidate()

Comment: <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkDytCAD" runat="server" 
                                    GroupName="Monedha" Text="CAD" CssClass="radioMarginLeft" onClick="ChkValidate()" ClientIDMode="Static" />

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need some sort of control when to try to select a checkbox.

Try this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(event) {
  if(maxCount == 5) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('So many checkboxes');
  }    
});
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DrKfE/817/

Comment: fistly this if(MaxCount <= 4) {
        disableIfNotChecked();
    } means that if max count is 1,2,3 or 4 my checkboxes will disable, when in fact its not this what i want. The other thing is that what i am trying to acomplish is, that if the user selects the 5 one, the code will count will say (sorry you cant select more than 4) ant than this checkbox will be unchecked automatically

Comment: Ok I think that I get you now. Check the answer.

Comment: You can change the value of the maxCount in the fiddle in order to check it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the function call inside your checkbox ChkValidate(this)

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ChkDytCAD" runat="server" GroupName="Monedha" Text="CAD" CssClass="radioMarginLeft" onClick="ChkValidate(this)" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Add the parameter to the function and at the end of the function uncheck it when you have 4 boxes ticked

```
function ChkValidate(checkbox) {
    ...
    if (MaxCount > 4) {
        checkbox.checked = false;
    }
}
```

this is a fiddle with an example, that does pretty much what you want, it will only let you check a maximum of 4 boxes at once https://jsfiddle.net/2p069wvb/8/

Comment: should i put this even somewhere else because nothing is happening

Comment: just add the if statement at the end of your function and add this to ChkValidate(this) in your asp:CheckBox and it should work